# Powershell set focus on new window

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I would like to run commands on new window that is started from scripts, like this:

```
function start() {

    start-process powershell; echo "test";


}
```

This command start new powershell window, but `echo "test"` is runned in old window, can I run commands in new window? I'm running Win7/64bit, Powershell v 4.0.

When I use

```
function start() {

    echo "test" | start powershell;


}
```

I'm getting this

```
start-process : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not
take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At C:\Users\Bane\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:50 char:15
+ echo "test" | start-process powershell;
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (test:PSObject) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

It opens new window but command is not runned.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe your problem rather than what you perceive as the solution. What do you ultimately want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: you should read up on the basics of powershell, for the beginning: `;` is used to seperate commands, `|` is the pipe operator which forwards the ouptut of the function in front of it to the function after it. If you want to learn in powershell i suggest you use the `get-help ` cmdlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = '-noexit -command "echo test"'
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList $args
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed xD.

Answer (score 2):

With `;` you are actually running the commands separately. Instead use `-ArgumentList` command option to provide the command or script you want to be executed like below

```
start-process powershell.exe -wait -verb open -ArgumentList "echo Test test";
```

So, your code should look like

```
function start() 
{
 start-process powershell.exe -wait -verb open -ArgumentList "echo Test test";
}
```